# Colimi of Poset

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to make sense of following proposition.

Let $A$ be a collection of subsets of set $S$. Regard $A$ as poset under $\subseteq$. Suppose $A$ has the following property. For all $s \in S$ and $T,U \in A$, if $s \in T \cap U$, there exists $V \in A$ such that $s \in V \subseteq T \cap U$.

Then the map $colim_{T \in A} T \to \cup_{T \in A} T$ sending $[(T,t)]$ to $t$ is a bijection.

The hint for the proof says I should try to prove that $(T,t) \sim (T',t')$ iff $t = t'$.

[image]

Another relevant part is that for $F \colon C \to Set$, the colimit can be explicitly computed as taking the disjiont union $\cup_{c \in C} F(c)$, and quotienting by the equivalence relation generated by $(c, x \in F(c) ) \sim (c', x' \in F(c'))$ if there is $\alpha \colon c \to c'$ with $F(\alpha)(x) = x'$.

[image]

Now for proposition 5.8, I believe $colim_{T \in A} T$ refers to taking the colimi of functor $F \colon A \to Set$ where we send $T \in A$ to $T$ and send morphism $T \subseteq S$ to the inclusion $T \to S$.

If this is correct, $(T,t) \sim (T',t')$ iff $t = t'$ seems clear because $F$ sends $\subseteq$ to inclusion.

But I'm not sure how to use this to reach the conlusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(T,t)$ and $(T',t)$. Choose $V$ so that $t \in V \subseteq T \cap T'$. Then $(V,t) \sim (T,t)$ and $(V,t) \sim (T',t)$, so $(T,t) \sim (T',t)$. Hence, $[(T,t)]$ bijectively correspond to $t$.